# Azure DevOps Epic/Feature Timeline Items in Removed State Spanning Multiple Sprints

Tags: azure-devops, timeline, epic

I am trying to view the Epic/Feature Timeline and noticing completed Epics, Features and Stories are spanning all sprints.  I am wondering if this has to do with Stories and Bugs with a state of Removed because Removed is not considered a final state so DevOps is considering those Stories and Bugs to not be resolved?

Is there a way to make Removed a final state or is there a workaround for this (other than deleting all removed items)?

Thank you to anyone that can provide direction.

Shad

FYI - I tried to filter to only states I wanted listed in the backlog but this did nothing to the timeline and expanded all items within the epics.

Answer (score 0):

`Removed` state is not considered a final state and DevOps doesn’t think those Stories and Bugs are not resolved.
Here is workflow state (Agile process) and you can see that `Removed`  state is designed an independent branch flow, So `Removed` state can’t be  made to a  final state in this design pattern.

Work items in a state mapped to the Removed category are hidden from the backlog and board experiences .You can’t see removed state work items in Feature Timeline but still list these items using a query.
Please refer to doc: [How workflow category states are used in Azure Boards backlogs and boards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/workflow-and-state-categories?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process)

[image: workflow]

However, there's a workaround to achieve it.

disable `Removed` State in process and add state name that's similar to `Removed` in complete type.(e.g：Removed back) .You'll see work items of `Removed back` state showing in Feature Timeline.
[image: disable removed state and add similar name]

Comment: Thank you for the insight.  I will try this to see if it works for us.  I appreciate the time you took to respond.  Will update this as answer if we can make this workaround work for us.

Comment: this still does not perform as expected.  i wanted the issues in question to be ignored by the timeline for a certain state but it does not look like that is possible without just removing the iteration.  so removing the iteration will be the desired workaround.  Appreciate you trying to assist.  thank you! - also if i am reading correctly, i am not an Azure DevOps expert for transparency, it seems like the timeline view is an extension and not supported by MS?!?

Comment: Extensions get published at [Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/azuredevops) where they can be kept private for you and your team or shared publicly with the millions of developers currently using Azure DevOps. 
The timeline extension is supported by MS. You can refer to :https://github.com/microsoft/featuretimeline. BTW you can build your extension and share it to marketplace.